# How to Give a Overlay Panel in sencha touch a transparent background

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-touch-2.1

The code below only changes the color of the border around the panel but not the panel itself.

```
var overlay = Ext.Viewport.add({                
    xtype: 'panel',
    centered: true,
    style:'background-color: transparent;',
    modal: {
        style: 'opacity: 0'
    },
    hideOnMaskTap:true,
    width:'20%',
    height: '50%',
    styleHtmlContent:true,
    items:[{
        xtype:'button',
        test:'hey',
        cls:'notrans',
        style: 'opacity: 1'
    }]
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to change the `x-panel-inner` cls for your panel when it is **centered**. So what you want to do is give your panel a `cls` e.g: `cls: my-panel`.

```
var overlay = Ext.Viewport.add({
    xtype: 'panel',
    centered: true,
    style:'background-color: transparent;',
    cls: 'my-panel',
    ....
});
```

Now in your custom stylesheet:

```
.my-panel .x-panel-inner {
    background-color: transparent !important;
}
```

So now your centered panel should have its background transparent.

Comment: it made the background change inner background change black

Comment: make sure your `style` config is set to : `background-color:transparent;` as well.