# Change Button Background Color Sencha Architect

Tags: sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

I'm trying to change the button background color on Sencha Architect 2

I tryied use cls, but it don't worked, I named the cls and used it on a css file, this is the simple script:

.btn //this is my cls name
{
    background-color:red;
}

Here a screen of the named cls:

[image]

Thanks for the help =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, You can just mention "Background" instead of "Background-color" ( or ) you can change the button color using inline "style" property under config. You just need to select the button --> Go to Config Panel --> Search for style property -> and type "background: red"[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing the `!important` at the end. So if your `cls` is `btn1`, You can do:

```
.btn1 {
    background-color:red !important
}
```

Perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15456061/how-to-give-a-overlay-panel-in-sencha-touch-a-transparent-background/15456934#15456934) could be of some reference:

Comment: Thanks guy, I made the test with !important but still don't working